# Magento 1.9.3 : Bundle product add to cart too slow

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

I want to add bundle product to add to cart from external php file and it is successfully adding but it is taking long time approx 30sec.

```
<?php 

include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default'); 
umask(0);

$size = 2;

$productId = 123; // bundle product

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->load($productId);

$product->addCustomOption('size',$size);
$session =  Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend")); // frontend session

//cart params
$cartParams = array(
            'product' => $productId,
            'related_product' => null,
            'bundle_option' => array(
                '3'=> '176399802',
                '4' => '176420135'
            ),
            'qty' => 1,
        );
try{
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart'); // cart object
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($product, $cartParams);
    $cart->save();
    $session->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    echo Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

and when I perform any action to cart page it is also taking time. Actions like ( load cart page, delete items etc )

Please look into this and help me to sort out this problem.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed slow add to cart issue for bundle product.

As I have gone through deeply and found that there are lot of bundle selection products( approx 20,000). I have created another bundle product with 10 bundle selection product and it worked fine and took 5 second.

As we know that when we add to cart the product, we call `$cart->addProduct($product,$params);`

where `$product` is object of product and `$params` is an array with respective selections product.

Due to lot of selection product, it is taking time during add to cart.